# Why does this ~ space not print within ExplSyntax command?

Tags: expl3, latex3, white-space

I am aware that `\ExplSyntaxOn` changes how spaces are interpreted. I use `~` to represent a space, but in this instance one of those tildes is not printed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Degrees Celcius.
\newcommand{\dc}[1]
{
    #1$^\circ$C
}

% Arguments: temperature (celsius) minumum minutes, maxiumum minutes, "until".
% "maximum minutes" may be blank.
% "until" may be blank.
\newcommand{\bakeat}[4]
{
    Bake~at~\dc{#1}~for~
    \ifthenelse
        {\equal{#3}{}}
        {#2}
        {#2~to~#3}
    ~minutes
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{.}{~until~#4.}
}

\begin{document}

\bakeat{180}{10}{15}{}

\end{document}
```

Here is how that renders:

[image]

It prints `15minutes` instead of `15 minutes`, even though there is clearly a tilde before the word `minutes` in the macro definition. Other tildes work as expected.

Why isn't this particular tilde-space printing?

Comment: Spaces, including `~`, are ignored at the beginning of lines; on the other hand `~` is not ignored at the end of lines.

Comment: This works :  {#2~to~#3}~

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spaces, including `~`, are ignored at the beginning of lines; on the other hand `~` is not ignored at the end of lines.

```
\newcommand{\bakeat}[4]
{
    Bake~at~\dc{#1}~for~
    \ifthenelse
        {\equal{#3}{}}
        {#2}
        {#2~to~#3}~
    minutes
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{.}{~until~#4.}
}
```

On the other hand, as you're using `expl3` it makes sense to use *all* its features.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Degrees Celsius.
\NewDocumentCommand{\dc}{m}
 {
    \SI{#1}{\celsius}
 }

% Arguments: temperature (celsius) minumum minutes, maxiumum minutes, "until".
% "maximum minutes" may be blank.
% "until" may be blank.
\NewDocumentCommand{\bakeat}{mmmm}
 {
    Bake~at~\dc{#1}~for~#2
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #3 } { ~to~#3}~minutes
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #4 } { ~until~#4}.
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\bakeat{180}{10}{}{}

\bakeat{180}{10}{15}{}

\bakeat{180}{10}{15}{ready}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might like a handier syntax:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Degrees Celsius.
\NewDocumentCommand{\dc}{m}
 {
    \SI{#1}{\celsius}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\bakeat}{m >{\SplitArgument{1}{-}}m o}
 {
    Bake~at~\dc{#1}~for~\bakerange#2~minutes
    \IfValueT { #3 } { ~until~#3 }.
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\bakerange}{mm}
 {
    #1\IfValueT{#2}{~to~#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\bakeat{180}{10}

\bakeat{180}{10-15}

\bakeat{180}{10-15}[ready]

\end{document}
```